Issue with the definition of derivative in normed vector spaces
Let $(V,\Vert\cdot\Vert_V)$ and $(W,\Vert\cdot\Vert_W)$ be normed vector spaces and let $f\colon U\to W$ be a function defined on an open set $U\subseteq V$. $f$ is said to be differentiable at $x\in U$ if and only if there exists $A\in B(V,W)$ such that
$$\lim_{\Vert h\Vert_V\to0}\frac{\Vert f(x+h)-f(x)-A(h)\Vert_W}{\Vert h\Vert_V}=0\tag1$$
If $f$ is differentiable at $x$, $A$ is called the derivative of $f$ at $x$. It may be denoted by $Df(x)$.
Now, I understand this definition. My problem is, it is not equivalent to the "classical" one when dealing with real functions of one real variable, that is
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h\tag2$$
In this case, the derivative is a real number, not a linear map. The linear map $A$ is the function $t\mapsto f'(x)t$.
So is the derivative of $f\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ defined by $(1)$ or by $(2)$? Why is there this discrepancy between the usual definition and its "generalization" (it's not a generalization, since they're not equivalent in the specific case?

In general, the idea is that the derivative of a function $f$ at a point $x$ is the "best linear approximation of $f$ at $x$".  This is what the more general formulation of the derivative encodes. In one dimension, linear functions correspond to multiplying by scalars. The best linear approximation of $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ at $x$ is multiplying by the slope of the tangent at $x$ aka the number $f'(x)$.

@Zorngo I get that, my issue was that when we talk about the derivative of a function $f\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ at a point $x$ we mean a real number corresponding to the slope of the tangent line, not a function $x\mapsto mx$ (where $m$ is such slope).

It is a generalization once you recognize that because in the case $V=\Bbb{R}$, the limit (2) exists if and only if the limit (1) exists (with $A$ being the linear map $t\mapsto f’(x)t$). More abstractly, we’re just using the canonical isomorphism $\text{Hom}(\Bbb{F},W)\cong W$ for any vector space $W$ over any field $\Bbb{F}$.
If you’re talking about the fact that the ‘objects’ are different, then you just need to recognize that having $\Bbb{R}$ as domain is VERY special, which is why you were able to get away with treating the derivative of a map $f:\Bbb{R}\to W$ at a point $a\in\Bbb{R}$ as an element $f’(a)\in W$. The general theory requires the full force of linear algebra, and you need to describe derivatives using linear maps.

But it's not true that the derivative at $x$ is the map $A$ when $f\in\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$.

@Elvis that’s just a double usage of terminology and you just have to get over it. anyway, it’s a generalization of the ‘idea’ if you wish, and you should refer to my first paragraph. Alternatively, you can call the first definition Frechet differentiability and you can call $A=Df(x)$ the Frechet derivative of $f$ at $x$. Then as a theorem you can state that when $V=\Bbb{R}$, the map is Frechet differentiable at a point if and only if it is ‘vanilla’ differentiable at that point at the two notions are related as in my first paragraph.

Oh, okay, thank you. That answers my question (I can't accept answers yet though).

@Elvis: By the way, there is a close connection between higher-order Fréchet derivatives and higher-order "vanilla" derivatives, too. For simplicity, suppose $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a smooth function and $x\in\mathbb R$. If I remember correctly, the $n$-th Fréchet derivative $D^nf(x)$ is an $n$-linear form $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ (or, at least, it is a linear map which, via currying, can be identified with an $n$-linear form), and evaluating that form at $(1,\dots,1)$ gives you $f^{(n)}(x)$, the vanilla $n$-th derivative at $x$.
